# How to produce Plotly treemap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to produce a plotly treemap and having trouble getting the code to work. In addition to getting the code running I would like for the the labels for percent to have a % sign at the end i.e. "15%". Any help is appreciated.

```
library(plotly)

dtd7 <- structure(
list(
topic = structure(
  c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
    5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
  .Label = c("Owners' Equivalent Rent of Residences", 
             "Rent of Primary Residence",
             "New Vehicles", "Used Cars and Trucks",
             "Cereals And bakery Prouducts",
             "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair", 
             "Airline Fares", 
             "Apparel", 
             "Alcoholic Bevreages", 
             "Hospital Services",
             "Tobacco and Smoking", 
             "Physicans Services", 
             "Gasoline All Types",
             "Electricity",
             "Utility (Piped) Gas Services",
             "Nonalcohoholic Beverages and Beverage Materials",
     "Food Away From Home",
"Meats Poultry Fish and",
"Fruits and Vegetables",
" Dairy and Related Products",
"Cereals And bakery Prouducts",
"Other Foods at Home"),
 n = structure(
  c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L,
    7L, 8L, 1L),
  .Label = c("6.7", "6.9", "1.4", "3.8", "19.2", "8.5", "12.1", "1.1", "5", "2.9", 
 "6.3", "7.7", "0.7",
             "8.9", "3.4", "10.4", "2.9", "5.3", "0.1", "0.4", "1.4", "3.4","3.3"),
  class = "factor"
)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-13L)
)

p <- plot_ly(
dtd7,
labels = ~ topic,
parents = NA,
values = ~ n,
type = 'treemap',
hovertemplate = "Category: %{label}<br>Percent: %{value}<extra></extra>"
)

p
```

Answer (score 1):

With minor changes you can get the desired behaviour. Changes are commented in the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

dtd7 <- structure(
  list(
    topic = structure(
      c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
      .Label = c("Owners' Equivalent Rent of Residences", "Rent of Primary Residence",
                 "New Vehicles", "Used Cars and Trucks", "Cereals And bakery Products",
                 "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair", "Airline Fares",
                 "Apparel", "Alcoholic Beverages", "Hospital Services",
                 "Tobacco and Smoking", "Physicians Services", "Gasoline All Types",
                 "Electricity", "Utility (Piped) Gas Services",
                 "Nonalcoholic Beverages and Beverage Materials",
                 "Food Away From Home", "Meats Poultry Fish and", 
                 "Fruits and Vegetables", "Dairy and Related Products",
                 "Cereals And bakery Products", "Other Foods at Home"),
      class = "factor"),
    n = structure(
      c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L),
      .Label = c("6.7", "6.9", "1.4", "3.8", "19.2", "8.5", "12.1", "1.1", "5", "2.9", 
                 "6.3", "7.7", "0.7", "8.9", "3.4", "10.4", "2.9", "5.3", "0.1", "0.4", 
                 "1.4", "3.4", "3.3"),
      class = "factor")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -13L)
)


  
plot_ly(
    dtd7 %>% 
      mutate(n = as.numeric(as.character(n))), #transform to numeric
    labels = ~topic,
    parents = NA,
    values = ~n,
    type = 'treemap',
    hovertemplate = "Category: %{label}<br>Percent: %{value}%<extra></extra>" #added % after value!
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way for me to change the colors so that they are shades of a single color with the largest rectangle being the darkest and the smallest being the lightest?

Comment: Also I'm noticing that some of my categories like "Dairy and related products" does show up. Do you know how to fix this?